# How can I change default JWT security key of ThingsBoard?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to make proxy for ThingsBoard.

My proxy try to validate jwt key before passing it to ThingsBoard.

My trial was `grep` for https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard.  But I failed to find it.

But I don't know what is default JWT security key of ThingsBoard.    How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found default key by myself.

Default security key is "thingsboardDefaultSigningKey", and it is coded in `thingsboard.yml`